# Error in Angular 5 projects which use angular2-logger

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I'm using angular2-logger version 0.6.0 in an Angular CLI project. When I try to upgrade to Angular CLI 1.5 and Angular 5, the following error occurs

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\test\sample-5\sample\node_module\angular2-logger\app\core\level.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\test\sample-5\sample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:624:23)
at plugin.done.then (C:\test\sample-5\sample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
at <anonymous>
@ ./node_modules/angular2-logger/core.js 6:9-36
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

This is app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Logger } from 'angular2-logger/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [Logger],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This sample project is created by `ng new sample`, so every settings are Angular CLI default.

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary solution.

Go to **node_modules\angular2-logger\app\core** and there remove all of the .ts files.

More info:
https://github.com/code-chunks/angular2-logger/issues/175

Answer (score 0):

Temprory Solution that worked for me.
the installed package has a dist dir `node_modules/angular2-logger/dist/es6/`.

in `node_modules/angular2-logger/package.json` `main` is set to

`"main": "./dist/cjs/core.js",`

change this to

`"main": "./dist/es6/core.js",`

You may have a different dir structure as `dist` is created during installation process. So the goal shouls be to point main to compiled `core.js` file.

Change all the import statements for `Logger` to

`import { Logger } from 'angular2-logger';`

Compile and run and stay happy.

I don't know wheather this is a typo or delibrate decision, but this works even for `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

From the linked angular2-logger issue:

> As the error states, you need to include a reference to the Typescript
>   files that are imported by angular2-logger so TypeScript is aware of
>   them. Edit the tsconfig.json (or tsconfig.app.json if you're using the
>   angular cli) to include the following snippet:

```
"include": [
    "../node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts",
    "../node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/logger.ts",
    "../node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/providers.ts",
    "**/*.ts"
],
```

*The paths may change depending on your node_modules and tsconfig.json location. I had to use like this:

```
"node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts",
```

Since i am not a wildcard fan, i removed the last line "**/*.ts" and got erros about the files, which are located directly under src. So i ended up listing those also on the list. This is the result, which worked for me:

```
  "include": [
    "node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/logger.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/providers.ts",
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ]
```